# Locomotion of Hydra: Why Somersaulting is better than Loop locomotion when moving to a larger distance?

Tags: zoology, homework, locomotion

In my text I read about different types of locomotion of Hydra where I learnt that generally Hydra moves by somersaulting and it is faster than 'Loop locomotion' which Hydra uses for moving to a large distance. At the end of the chapter the question is "Why somersaulting is better for going to a larger distance?" I cannot find a good answer to it.

Comment: Is not saving time a good enough argument?

Comment: generally Hydra moves by somersaulting and it is faster than 'Loop locomotion' which Hydra uses for moving to a large distance. by 'Which' I mean 'loop locomotion' so in fact, when Hydra goes to a larger distance it chooses the slower process